# Pasar valores Int de Array a valores String

Tags: java

Estoy implementando un programilla novatero, en el cual por medio de un random te arroja 9 numeros de 2 cifras cada uno, comprendido entre el 10-99. De este estilo [32, 104, 75, 38, 92, 13, 92, 72, 73].
El número me lo arroja wuay, pero a la hora de acertarlo y pasarlo a XX(Como si hubiese acertado el número) pues me arroja error, normal dado que estoy tratando un int como si fuese un String. Hay alguna manera de castearlo o algún metodo?.
Adjunto programilla en cuestión:

```
public class Bucles {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        boolean empezar = false;
        int respuesta = 1;
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        int valor = 0;
        int[] primitiva = new int[9];
        int contador=0;

        System.out.println("Bienvenido al juego de la Primitiva:                       ");
        System.out.println("Tendrás que acertar los 9 números para llevarte un pellizco");
        System.out.println("¡¡¡¡ MUCHA SUERTE !!!!");
        System.out.println();

        while (empezar = true || contador==15 ) {

            /*System.out.println("¿Quieres empezar a jugar? SI(1)/NO(2)");
            empezar = teclado.nextBoolean();*/

            System.out.println("********************PRIMITIVA******************************");
            System.out.println(" Este es el número de Primitiva es : ");

            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

                valor = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 99 + 10);
                primitiva[i] = valor;
            }
            
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(primitiva));

            System.out.println("Dame un número entre el 10-99, ambos incluidos");
            respuesta=teclado.nextInt();
            for (int i : primitiva) {
                if(respuesta==primitiva[i]){
                    //primitiva[i]= Integer("XX");
                }
            }

        }

    }

}

---

Integer.parseInt("XX") ??

Por otra la variable empezar me casca un error al pedirle por consola (1=true/0=false)
```

Comment: Creo que no estoy entendiendo bien tu pregunta. ¿ Quieres convertir el String "XX" en int ?

Comment: Que error marca y define que es lo que deseas realizar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1-debes tener en cuenta que al generar tus valores aleatorios estos no deben repetirse

2-genera primero un arreglo aleatorio de tipo int y luego creas un arreglo de tipo String a los cuales pasaras esos valores de tipo int con un for y String.valueOf()
,de esa manera puedes reemplazar el acierto por "XX"

Te adjunto el codigo

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;


public class Bucle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int respuesta;
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] primitiva;
        String []primitiva2=new String[9];
        int contador=15;
        int cuenta=0;

        System.out.println("Bienvenido al juego de la Primitiva:                       ");
        System.out.println("Tendrás que acertar los 9 números para llevarte un pellizco");
        System.out.println("¡¡¡¡ MUCHA SUERTE !!!!");
        System.out.println();

        primitiva=new Random().ints(10, 99).distinct().limit(9).toArray();

        for (int i=0;i<9;i++ ) {
            primitiva2[i]=String.valueOf(primitiva[i]);
        }

        while(cuenta!=9 && contador!=0){
            System.out.println("********************PRIMITIVA******************************");
            System.out.println(" Este es el número de Primitiva es : ");

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(primitiva2));
            contador--;
            System.out.println("Dame un número entre el 10-99, ambos incluidos");
            respuesta=teclado.nextInt();
            for (int i=0;i<primitiva.length;i++) {
                if (String.valueOf (respuesta).equals (primitiva2[i])) {
                    primitiva2[i] = "XX";
                    cuenta++;
                    System.out.println ("acierto quedan " + contador + " intentos");
                }
            }

        }

        if(cuenta==9){
            System.out.println("\nFelicidades as Ganado");
        }else{
            System.out.println("\nSuerte para la proxima te faltaron los siguientes numeros");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(primitiva2));
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Grande @Dramaturgo, Con solo un arreglo de tipo String no te valdría? que metodo en el Random es el que hace que no se repita la misma secuencia de números?

Comment: @Arkaitxiki es que el array de numeros random se genera como int ,es por eso que usas 2 arreglos ,el metodo que te devulve 9 numeros random sin repetirse es el siguiente primitiva=new Random().ints(10, 99).distinct().limit(9).toArray(); podrias parsear ese metodo y obtener solo un arreglo de String,yo lo hago en dos , por debageo

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es parsear tu entrada por consola, de String a int tienes dos opciones:

```
Integer.parseInt(str);
Integer.valueOf(str);
```

empezar te casca por que lo que estas buscando es el siguiente boolean y le estas pasando un String. Prueba a castear ese String si es 1 = true y si es 2 = false.